# Is there IndexChanged event for grid in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica has plenty of events for views like Row_Updated, Field_Updated. I search for something like Index_Changed event but for now I can't find. Does it have some other name or exists at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no row selected index changed event that will bubble up to the graph. Instead there's a bunch of mechanisms designed to solve a narrow problem that would have required that missing event, these are the likes of DependOnGrid, StateColumn, AutoCallback/Refresh, Sync Position etc.

The reasoning behind this design could be to reduce the number of callbacks from the webpage to the server. From the user point of view, changing row selection is not a transactional operation. Having the webpage wait for the server at that time would make the webpage appear sluggish.